# Change WebBrowser content before document completed

Tags: c#, html, winforms, .net-4.5

I have a WebBrowser control and I am navigating to some local html page.
I have some code:

```
webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += OnDomContentLoaded;
public void OnDomContentLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var browser = (sender as WebBrowser);

    if (browser != null && browser.Document != null && browser.Document.Body != null)
    {
        var documentHtml = browser.Document.Body.InnerHtml;
        browser.Document.Body.InnerHtml = Helper.ModifyContent(documentHtml);
    }
}
```

In Helper.ModifyContent I am modifying html content. And I have one problem: html page loads and then it's being modified (I see for a few milliseconds that html content is changing). How can I change html content before it's shown in WebBrowser? And I can't use such methods as GetElementById() and similar.

Comment: use `<body style="visibility:hidden">` after change your body element then change `visibility:hidden` to `visibility:visible`

Comment: @jradich1234 it's interesting solution. But is there any other way to do that without modifiing the html page with some attributes? Any solution in WebBrowser control?